# Парсинг вложенных массивов json C#

Tags: c#, json.net

[state.json](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ue6BAem3rb8Pra5gQXkoKsCFkc909nUz)

Нужно для каждого штата, достать его координаты. Как спарсить это с помощью json.net?

Answer (score -2):

както так

Ну как то так получить 3600 значений сколько должно быть если знаешь проверь

Тут с именами штатов

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var text = File.ReadAllText("we.json");

        dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text);


        var indexes = new List<string>();
        foreach (var VARIABLE in json)
        {
            indexes.Add(VARIABLE.ToString().Split(':')[0].Replace("\"", string.Empty));
        }


        var points = new List<Point>();

        var states = new List<State>();

        foreach (var key in indexes)
        {
            var count = json[key].Count;

            var state = new State {Name = key};
            states.Add(state);

            if (count == 1)
            {
                foreach (var inner in json[key][0])
                {
                    state.Points.Add(new Point { X = inner[0], Y = inner[1] });
                }
            }

            if (count > 1)
            {
                foreach (var inner in json[key])
                {
                    foreach (var innerIn in inner)
                    {
                        if (innerIn.Count == 1)
                            state.Points.Add(new Point { X = innerIn[0], Y = innerIn[1] });
                        if (innerIn.Count > 1)
                        {
                            foreach (var inn in innerIn)
                            {
                                state.Points.Add(new Point { X = inn[0], Y = inn[1] });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }



        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}


class Point
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
}


class State
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Point> Points { get; set; } = new List<Point>();
}
```

Comment: мля за что минус та!!!!

Comment: Хоть минус и не мой, но постараюсь вам ответить на этот вопрос: 1. Это явный дубликат, советую в будущем перед публикацией ответа проверять, есть ли что то похожее. 2. Это костыль. Обычно такое делается путем создания конвертера или чего то в этом духе и работа ведется с самим JSON объектом (его десериализацией), вы же делаете `.Split(':')` и уйму лишних действий. 3. Это не ответ на вопрос, ибо сам вопрос был в "Как спарсить это", а не как работать с данными после. Вы лучше бы рассказали почему используете `dynamic` и как конкретно вытянуть нужное значение. В общем выбирайте, за что минус...

Comment: минус мой, так как тот способ, что вы описали, это костыль. Парсить тип в `dynamic` и потом шарить по нему - это как вредные советы давать. Ваш код может и рабочий, но он 1) Непонятный 2) неподдерживаемый 3) безпричинный. Зачем это делать так, когда можно составить верную модель и десериализовать? Вы стреляете себе в ногу таким кодом, за это я поставил минус. На ревью я бы такое не пропустил. Извиняюсь. что сразу фидбек не написал, отвлекся.

Comment: не в продакш же пускаем

Comment: @Саске ваш пример не работает. Я посмотрел темы-дубликаты и это мне не помогло. У меня вся сложность задания в том , что в штате может быть вложенность массива как 4 скобки , так и 2 . В какой объект это десериализовать?

Comment: @вася курочкин все работает отлично

Comment: @Саске  извиняюсь, не  доглядел. Все верно

Comment: @tym32167 прикол в том что скруткура json убогая и так проще как я сделал

Comment: Структуру я не вижу, примера её нет ни в вопросе (по ссылкам куда то там я не считаю, у мнея все заблочено), ни в вашем ответе. Обоснования, почему именно вы костыль выбрали тоже нет. Вы, по сути, просто кинули портянку кода, без какиз то вообще пояснений. Потому я понял как понял и заминусил. Если вдруг будете ответ обновлять, меня пинганите, я его перечитаю

Comment: ща покажу структуру

Comment: @tym32167 https://jsfiddle.net/youprjkq/  вот в консоль посмотри вывод

Comment: @Саске я бы поглядел, но у меня firewall режет всё, у меня ни ссылки такие не работают, ни гугл драйвы, ни чат. Я даже картинки на сайте не вижу. Потому либо пример добавьте в ответ. либо я погляжу из дома, вечером. через часов 6-7